# css question for vbulletin forum

Tags: html, css, vbulletin

I'm trying to move the "likes" gray bar right above the signature, to the left of the "like" link found on top right w/ tiny icon.

Example:
http://www.talkjesus.com/bible-study-hall/44722-antimonianism.html#post220422

The css code now

```
.vbseo_buttons .vbseo_liked {
    background: rgba(46, 53, 57, .8);
        color: #fff;
        border: 0;
    -moz-border-radius: 3px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
    border-radius: 3px; 
    clear: both;
    display: block;
    padding: 12px;
    margin: 5px 30px;
    <vb:if condition="$stylevar['textdirection'] == 'rtl'">
        background-position: right;
    </vb:if>
}
```

If I change display: block to display: inline, it'll move it to the same row, like this:
http://i49.tinypic.com/348lonc.png

However, it loses the margin property and width property. I tried fixing the width by adding width: 50%; but that changed nothing. How can I keep it inline while fixing margin and width?

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean your want the gray bar at the far top right where it shows the quantity of likes the thread has with the heart? To keep the margin you should just float the gray box

Floated left

```
.vbseo_buttons .vbseo_liked {
background: rgba(46,53,57,.8);
color: #fff;
border: 0;
-moz-border-radius: 3px;
-webkit-border-radius: 3px;
border-radius: 3px;
clear: both;
padding: 12px;
margin: 5px 30px;
float: left;
}
```

To move this all the way to the top right you would need to modify the template and it would end up looking something like this but you need to move the entire `after_content` div or restyle it as needed if only moving the vbseo_liked container. And also remove the clear:both style.

[image]

Comment: Hi Anagio, no I want it left aligned with the "like" link inside the post itself instead. Thanks.

Comment: @ServerSideX well it appears the like link inside the post itself is only visible to members who are logged in. To put it there is pretty simple CSS. I'm just not taking the time to register